# ScrollableControl scroll bars always return to zero

Tags: c#, winforms

hopefully this is an easy one!

I'm deriving from `UserControl`, and I am overriding `OnPaint`.  I want this control to be scrollable, but all I want is to be able to get the value of the scroll bars and handle where to draw everything myself. I have set up the following:

```
// How the hell do I get this scrolling to not return to zero?
this.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(TimelineControl_Scroll);

this.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = true;
this.HorizontalScroll.Visible = true;
this.HorizontalScroll.Minimum = 0;

this.VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;
this.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;

this.AutoScroll = false;
```

I am seeing the new value of the scroll position. However, the scroll bars always return to zero.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reverse-engineer what that code is trying to do.  AutoScroll is your friend.  Here's an example:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {
    public UserControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(1000, 0);
    }
    protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se) {
        base.OnScroll(se);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.AutoScrollPosition.X, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 1000, this.ClientSize.Height);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I was scared of AutoScroll because I didn't understand the documentation - and AutoScrollMinSize is a pretty poor name, IMO. Should be called InnerWidth or MaxWidth or something. It is the maximum width of the scrollable control, right? and Width is the visible width.

Comment: Regardless, AutoScroll is now my friend! Thank you!
I was doing some Translations on the Graphics before, but I just had to make some relatively minor changes to get it to work with this new model. Thanks again!