# ScrollableControl resets ScrollBar Value after user scrolled

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, scrollbars

I'm writing an image viewer control in C# inheriting from `ScrollableControl`. It allows zooming and panning the view on the image and has scroll bars reflecting the visible image area.

I'm using the integrated `HorizontalScroll` and `VerticalScroll` and could implement updating them to appear as expected (setting `Visible`, `Maximum`, `LargeChange` and`Value` most prominently):

```
SizeF viewSize = new SizeF(ClientSize.Width / Zoom, ClientSize.Height / Zoom);
SizeF freeTopLeft = new SizeF(-_offset.X, -_offset.Y);
SizeF freeBotRight = new SizeF(
    viewSize.Width - ImageSize.Width - freeTopLeft.Width,
    viewSize.Height - ImageSize.Height - freeTopLeft.Height);
// Horizontal
if (freeTopLeft.Width < 0 || freeBotRight.Width < 0)
{
    HorizontalScroll.Visible = true;
    HorizontalScroll.Maximum = (int)ImageSize.Width;
    HorizontalScroll.LargeChange = (int)viewSize.Width;
    HorizontalScroll.Value = (int)-freeTopLeft.Width;
}
else
{
    HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
}
// Vertical same as horizontal using Height, removed for brevity.
```

When the user drags the scrollbar thumb, I correctly update the displayed part of the image as follows in `OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)`:

```
switch (se.ScrollOrientation)
{
    case ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll:
        _offset.X = se.NewValue;
        break;
    case ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll:
        _offset.Y = se.NewValue;
        break;
}
Refresh();
```

However, as soon as the user releases the mouse button he dragged the thumb with, both scroll bars jump back to `Value` 0. It does not create another `OnScroll` event, so my image still shows the expected part, but the scroll bars "desynced" with what is displayed:
[image: Scroll bar thumb jumping back]

I checked many times if my code somehow manipulates the `Value` unexpectedly while and after scrolling, but I never set that property erroneously.
I also tried setting the ScrollBar values manually in `OnScroll`, but it did not help.

What do I need to do to correctly keep the thumb in place? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All the hacks and workarounds that would let you hold value there are just not worth it... better just add HScroll, VScroll, Sizer or whatever it is called and be done with this WinForms bug.

Comment: How are there many hacks and workarounds to store the offset I require for drawing? What is the usual way of doing things?

Comment: So there is this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/437437c8-9548-4e68-8f17-356f848f379d/scroll-reset-when-control-focused?forum=winforms. The way it was intended to work was to have ScrollableControl would show scrolls when content is outside of view. But it fails, when forced to be displayed in different settings(like a viewport for renderer). You could use the one solution I gave. I also found (can't find it now) some workaround on microsoft connect. I tried it all myself and some more. All fails. Not worth it.

Comment: I see... WinForms disappointment once again. I'm not sure when I get to check back on this old project to create manual scroll bars (though I'd still prefer a solution for `ScrollableControl` on this answer, if anyone knows it). Especially since I'm using WPF since a year now for anything new.

Comment: Using AutoScroll as described in here can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019877/scrollablecontrol-scroll-bars-always-return-to-zero